# grab tensorflow prediction accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, prediction

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(".\\models\\dogandcat")
prediction = model.predict([prepare(pic)])  
if CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])] == 'Dog':
        print('Dog')
```

This is my current code for grabbing the type of image. Once it's detected the dog, I'm trying to make it see how sure/accurate the detection is. Hopefully, that makes sense?

Comment: We need more details, especially your model architecture.

Answer (score 1):

If by

> I'm trying to make it see how sure/accurate the detection is...

you mean the probability the model gave to the image for the "dog" type, then you should just take the logits and look at the index of a dog (which can be inferred from your CATEGORIES variable).

*logits* are the output of the last softmax layer of your model.

Comment: Maybe a code example would help him and others like me